# Текст находится в за пределами div

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

На дисциплине "Тестирование и отладка ПО", препод дал задание написать интернет-магазин на любую тематику и я выбрал магазин плюшевых игрушек но вот текст "Приветики" находится за пределами div. Почему?

```css
body {
  background-image: url(Images/BGI.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
.Container {
  float: right;
  width: 600px;
  height: 800px;
}
.opacitydiv {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: white;
}
.RegistaryForm {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/App_Themes/Styles/RegisterStyle.css" type="text/css" />
  <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 820px; height: 600px; margin: auto">
    <div class="Container">

      <div class="opacitydiv"></div>

      <div class="RegistaryForm">

        Приветики
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 220px; height: 220px;">
      <a href="~/Home/Index/">
        <!--<img src="~/App_Themes/Styles/Images/Logo.png" width="220" height="220" style="border-radius: 220px;" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Скрин 1]

[image: Скрин 2]

Comment: а как должно быть к итоге?

Answer (score 1):

**Во-первых** у вас не закрытый комментарий. Нужно добавить `-->` после закрытия тега `img`

```
<!--<img src="~/App_Themes/Styles/Images/Logo.png" width="220" height="220" style="border-radius: 220px;" /> -->
```

**Во-вторых** у вас блок `<div class="opacitydiv"></div>` имеет 100% высоты родительского класса, поэтому следующий блок после него `<div class="RegistaryForm">` располагается под ним.

**В третьих** как так, что у вас первый `div` имеет `600px` высоты, а дочерний элемент `<div class="Container">` имеет `800px`?

### Решение

Убрать высоту у блока `<div class="opacitydiv"></div>`

```
.opacitydiv {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; // убрать
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Либо разместить блок `<div class="RegistaryForm">` внутрь блока `<div class="opacitydiv"></div>`

```
<div class="opacitydiv">
    <div class="RegistaryForm">
        Приветики
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если я уберу опасити, то я уберу полупрозрачный задний фон который мне так нужен именно такого размера, не больше не меньше.

Comment: @Алексей я предложил не opacity убирать, а высоту. Тогда расскажите где должен быть ваш текст?

Comment: Простите ошибся, ну если я уберу высоту то исчезнет сам фон, размер его будет равен нулю пикселей и его не будет. Но я просто не могу понять почему слои находятся так как надо три слоя друг на друге, но всё содержимое этого дива находится ниже него?

Comment: @Алексей у вас `.opacitydiv` имеет высоту 100% и следующий блок за ним `.RegistaryForm` у которого убрано свойство `float` распологается под ним. Это обычное поведение блочных элементов

Comment: а как сделать что бы распологалось не под ним, а над ним? И что бы все размеры остались, z-index указан верно.

Comment: @Алексей `z-index` тут вообще не причем, `z-index` отвечает за уровень слоя наложения. Вот пример – https://jsfiddle.net/6dkcxhrp/

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29162/discussion-between-korytoff-and-).

Answer (score 1):

Имеется не закрытый комментарий:

```
<!--<img src=
```

уберите его или закройте.

Comment: это лишь одна проблема, которая не является ответом

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background-image: url(Images/BGI.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
.Container {
  float: right;
  width: 600px;
  height: 800px;
}
.opacitydiv {
  
}
.RegistaryForm {
 
  z-index: 2;
  float: none;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/App_Themes/Styles/RegisterStyle.css" type="text/css" />
  <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 820px; height: 600px; margin: auto">
    <div class="Container">

      <div class="opacitydiv"></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="RegistaryForm">

        Приветики
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 220px; height: 220px;">
      <a href="~/Home/Index/">
        <img src="~/App_Themes/Styles/Images/Logo.png" width="220" height="220" style="border-radius: 220px;" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```